# What's the trick to shaking the berry trees?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

Every now and then I come across a Berry tree, which I shake for Berries. You can shake the tree multiple times with more and more berries falling out of it.

However, occasionally a Pokemon encounter falls out of the tree, and once the encounter with it is done, some of the previously dropped off berries have been 'eaten by nearby Pokemon'.

Is there a trick to knowing how long to shake the tree?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The trick is to watch the tree after berries have dropped.

- If there is **no** movement in the tree, it should be perfectly safe to continue shaking it.
- If there is **occasional** movement (leaves rustling every 2-3 seconds), there is a **low** chance of encountering a Pokemon.

  - I have personally never had an encounter when the tree shakes like this, but @Roybin93 confirms it's possible, if a low chance.
- If there is **rapid** movement (leaves rustling every second), there is a **high** chance a Pokemon will fall out.

  - I have actually managed to shake the tree successfully again at this stage, meaning it's not a guarantee that a Pokemon will fall out.

You do seem to get a higher berry yield from shaking at rapid movement as well, so there is greater reward for the risk of losing the berries you've currently dropped.

Comment: It can also happen that there is **no movement** at all when shaking for the first time. Maybe even for a few times in a row, but I have never had that. 
I am also not sure if it is guaranteed to not having a Pokemon encounter in those cases but I could imagine it is at least lower than the one with **occasional** movement.
But I can confirm that you can encounter Pokemon even with **occasional** movement in the trees.

Comment: @Roybin93 I finally managed to get a tree with no movement for the first 2 shakes, so I can confirm it's possible. I have updated my answer to reflect that as well.

Comment: Come to think of it: I have shaken a lot of berry trees lately and not once gotten an encounter while it had occasional movement. I don't know if I was just not paying enough attention when I had that one encounter mentioned in my first comment. But now I think it had to be a tree with rapid movement. I guess you can not encounter Pokemon while the tree is shaking occasionally.